# Combining columns of multiple files while matching the order based on a different column and adding 0 for missing values

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, data-processing

I have multiple files I'd like to combine in a weird way.

Let's say this is one of my files:

```
1     group1
5     group5
6     group9
10     group3
2     group10
```

And this is another file:

```
0.1     group3
3     group5
52     group2
11     group4
8     group10
```

I'd like to combine these files into a new file such that I get:

```
       File1     File2
group1     1     0
group2     0     52
group3     10     0.1
group4     0     11
group5     5     3
group9     6     0
group10     2     8
```

So:
- The values from a column are combined based on the annotation in another column.
- If the file is missing value for a given annotation, it gets "0".
- Filename becomes the header, the "annotations" become the row names in the new file.

Is there a way to do this using bash scripting (or some other convenient way)? I have a few thousands of these files so it's really not an option to do it manually...

Thank you very much!

**Edit**: I guess I could follow some steps like:
1) I have a list of all possible annotations. For every file (iterating over each), I could check if an annotation exists, if not, I could insert a new line to the file:

```
0     annotation
```

2) I could sort every file alphabetically
3) Then I could merge them all into one file (and somehow figure out the header thing here)

Does anyone have ideas for any of these steps?

Comment: I have tried combining the annotation columns and value columns of multiple files into one file using awk, but matching order, and filling out missing values seemed to be non-trivial things to figure out afterwards. I think my problem isn't so much joining them, but mostly matching the annotations and filling out values for "missing annotations" while combining. I am not yet sure how to do those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { ++n }
{ a[$2,n]=$1;b[$2] }
END {
  for (c in b) {
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
      $i=((c,i) in a?a[c,i]:0)
    $1=(c OFS $1)
    print
  }
}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Hash the 2nd field plus the index of file on the command line with the 1st field in an array, and keep unique annotations in another array as a reference so that we can loop through the first array.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am not sure what I have done wrong but I seem to get the following output:  
 0 522  \\
group10 2 8  0 114  \\
6 0p9  \\
1 0p1 \\  
10 0.1 \\ 
Note: I am new to stackexchange and could not figure out how to add new lines in a comment. Please consider "\\" to be new lines.

Comment: @Matthew Do your files have DOS line endings? Run `cat -v file` and see if lines end in `^M`

Comment: We can't add new lines in comments :/

Comment: oh it is highly possible they are DOS formatted. I will fix that and try again. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried on two files and this worked well, thank you very much!